# Sprite size is different on the iphone and the simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

ON the simulator everything works great

when i call [sprite boundingbox] the results are different in cocos2d.

What might cause such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add it to the node before i called bounding box